# Grouping values based on sequence in SQL

Tags: sql, select, group-by, sequence

Is there a way to create just using select statements a table that contains in a column the range of the repeating values like in this example?

Example:

from the input table:

```
id value:
1 25
2 25
3 24
4 25
5 25
6 25
7 28
8 28
9 11
```

should result:

```
range value
1-2 25
3-3 24
4-6 25
7-8 28
9-9 11
```

Note: The id values from the input table are always in order and the difference between 2 values ordered by id is always equal to 1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: any RDBMS is good as long the select does what it should. I will adapt the query later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find sequences of consecutive values.  Here is one approach, using window functions:

```
select min(id), max(id), value
from (select id, value,
             row_number() over (order by id) as rownum,
             row_number() over (partition by value order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by (rownum - seqnum), value;
```

This takes into account that a value might appear in different places among the rows.  The idea is simple.  `rownum` is a sequential number.  `seqnum` is a sequential number that increments for a given value.  The difference between these is constant for values that are in a row.

Let me add, if you actually want the expression as "1-2", we need more information.  Assuming the id is a character string, one of the following would work, depending on the database:

```
select min(id)+'-'+max(id), . . .
select concat(min(id), '-', max(id)), . . .
select min(id)||'-'||max(id), . . .
```

If the id is an integer (as I suspect), then you need to replace the `id`s in the above expressions with `cast(id as varchar(32))`, except in Oracle, where you would use `cast(id as varchar2(32))`.

Comment: thanks that seems to work perfectly! I just test it on my set of data

Comment: The second row_number() expression needs an ORDER BY in its OVER clause. Even if the dialect of SQL doesn't require one, the query needs it (...partition by value order by id)...) to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT(MIN(id), '-', MAX(id)) AS id_range, value
  FROM input_table
 GROUP BY value
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
SELECT MIN(ID), MAX(ID), VALUE FROM TABLE GROUP BY VALUE
```